# How to change a "for loop" in a "foreach" loop in R to do it fast?

Tags: r, performance, foreach, parallel-processing

I'd like to change from "for loop" to "foreach" to do it fast. From spatial data, we can get X and Y coordination. In the case of New York, there are about 15,000 block groups. So, distance matrix(mat) can be 15,000*15,000 cells. I don't exactly know the reason, but it takes not much time to get distance matric(A). The issue is for loop. I need weight matrix (W) that indicates the nearest 100 block groups (neighbors). Following codes are working, but it's too slow. I'd like to change them more efficiently with using "foreach" and "parallel" library. Could you let me know how to change following for loop? Thank you so much.

````
```
coor<-cbind(UA$X, UA$Y) # X, Y coordination
A<-dist(coor, diag=T, upper=T) #distance b/w coor
mat <- as.matrix(A)
q<-100 # it can be changed
W<-array(0L, dim(A)) 

for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){
    W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]<-mat[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]
    D<-apply(W, 2, max, na.rm=TRUE)[i]
    W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]<-(1-(W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]/D)^3)^3 #tri-cube function
}
```
````

Something like...

````
```
coor<-cbind(UA$X, UA$Y) # X, Y coordination
A<-dist(coor, diag=T, upper=T) #distance b/w coor
mat <- as.matrix(A)
q<-100 # it can be changed
W<-array(0L, dim(A)) 

foreach::foreach(i = 1:nrow(mat)) %dopar% {
   W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]<-mat[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]
   D<-apply(W, 2, max, na.rm=TRUE)[i]
   W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]<-(1-(W[order(mat[,i])[1:q],i]/D)^3)^3 #tri-cube function
}
```
````

Comment: An easy way to speed this up would be to calculate `order(mat[,i])[1:q]` once at the start of the loop and reuse it, rather than doing it four times.

Comment: FWIW, foreach() is _not_ a for-loop. It works more like lapply(). If you can write your task using lapply(), then it's likely parallelizable, and then you can use foreach().  If you cannot write it using lapply(), it's unlikely to be parallelizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't well suited for parallelization. It would require too much overhead passing data back and forth. This is the kind of problem that nearest-neighbor algorithms and sparse matrices were made for.

```
set.seed(588345973)
x <- runif(15e3)
y <- runif(15e3)
q <- 100L

library(RANN)
library(Matrix)

system.time(
  W <- with(
    nn2(cbind(x, y), k = q),
    sparseMatrix(
      i = nn.idx,
      j = rep.int(1:length(x), q),
      x = c((1 - (nn.dists/nn.dists[,q])^3)^3)
    )
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.42    0.02    0.44
```

Compare to an optimized version of the original approach:

```
library(Rfast) # for `Dist`

system.time({
  mat <- Dist(cbind(x, y))
  W2 <- array(0, dim(mat))
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    o <- order(mat[,i])[1:q]
    W2[o,i] <- (1 - (mat[o,i]/mat[o[q],i])^3)^3
  }
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   13.07    1.11   14.19
```

Check that the results are equivalent:

```
all(sapply(1:length(x), \(i) all.equal(W[,i], W2[,i])))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's far better than before. I appreciate you!!

Comment: It can be made much faster still. See the update.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I checked and updated my codes. Thanks again!! Your codes are really helpful for me!!